# Calculate Pi with arbitrary precision digit by digit

Tags: c#, pi, arbitrary-precision

So I want to output Pi with arbitrary precision digit by digit. I found some code here https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pi#C.23

```
public IEnumerable<long> PiDigits(long b = 10)
    {
        BigInteger
            k = 1,
            l = 3,
            n = 3,
            q = 1,
            r = 0,
            t = 1
            ;

        // skip integer part
        var nr = b * (r - t * n);
        n = b * (3 * q + r) / t - b * n;
        q *= b;
        r = nr;

        for (; ; )
        {
            var tn = t * n;
            if (4 * q + r - t < tn)
            {
                yield return (long)n;
                nr = b * (r - tn);
                n = b * (3 * q + r) / t - b * n;
                q *= b;
            }
            else
            {
                t *= l;
                nr = (2 * q + r) * l;
                var nn = (q * (7 * k) + 2 + r * l) / t;
                q *= k;
                l += 2;
                ++k;
                n = nn;
            }
            r = nr;
        }
    }
```

And it's working correctly but there's no explanation to it. I want to understand this algorithm but it looks too complicated. And variables' name don't give me anything. So could you please tell me what algorithm is that co I could continue my research. Thank you!

Comment: This is Rabinowitz spigot algorithm, https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Algorithms/SpigotForPi.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation of the [spigot algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spigot_algorithm) translated from an implementation [by Jeremy Gibbons](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf).

His paper explains the inner workings of the algorithm. You should find the information you need at pages 5 and 6.